# How to change homotopy equivalences to homeomorphisms?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$ \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex} \newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex} \newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}$
Suppose we have $CW$-complex $X$. All the self-homotopy equivalences form a monoid, denote it by $G$.

Question: *is there any good way to construct another space $\widetilde X$, such that $\widetilde X$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$ and there exists a homomorphism from $G$ to the group $\widetilde G$ of all self-homeomorphisms of $\widetilde X$*?

A *good way* means that, (besides the functoriality) for any homotopy between elements of $G$ we should have an isotopy between corresponding elements of $\widetilde G$. Also, for every $f\in G$ the following diagram should be homotopy-commutative:

$$
\begin{array}{c} X & \ra{f} & X  \\  
\da{e} & & \da{e}  \\  
\widetilde X & \ra{\widetilde f} & \widetilde X\end{array}
$$

Here $e$ is a fixed homotopy equivalence between $X$ and $\widetilde  X$.

(I have one idea how to change all the homotopy equivalence to the homeomorphisms using mapping telescope, but I don't know what to do with homotopies and isotopies)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "all the self-homotopy equivalences form a groupoid." Do you have in mind the groupoid whose objects are homotopy equivalences and morphisms are homotopy classes of homotopies between them? And if so, are you ignoring the structure given by composition of homotopy equivalences?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan sorry, here must be _monoid_ instead of _groupoid_, i forgot the right word. of course, compositions of homotopy equivalences are very important (and homotopies are important too, as it written below)

Comment: I still do not really understand the question. I think it shouldn't be hard to come up with examples where the monoid of self homotopy equivalences is not cancellative and so does not embed into any group whatsoever. (In practice it seems more natural to consider composition only up to coherent homotopy; that is, $G$ is not really a monoid but a grouplike $E_1$ space.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think that's the right way to get a counterexample. Consider $S^1$, $f\colon S^1\to S^1$ the map which collapses the southern hemisphere and $g\colon S^1\to S^1$ a non-trivial homeomorphism which is the identity on the northern hemisphere. Then $f=fg$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thanks for your remarks. in fact, the following condition is necessary: if $f,g\in G$ are _not homotopic_, then the corresponding elements $\widetilde f,\widetilde  g\in\widetilde G$ are not homotopic too. but this condition holds automatically, so the map $G\to\widetilde G$ should be an arbitrary homomorphism

Comment: @FernandoMuro this example doesn't work in case when the map $G\to\widetilde G$ is not required to be bijective. in fact, for most of manifolds (i think)  every class of self-homotopy equivalence can be represented by a homeomorphism, and every homotopy -- by an isotopy.

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev that's not accurate, an embedding suffices to reach a contradiction. Embedding was your condition in the previous versions of your question, not homomorphisms. Of course, if you change the statement, the answer changes, but for the question you started with, Qiaouchu's comment and my tiny contribution provide a negative answer.

Comment: @FernandoMuro thank you, i see the contradiction with the first state of my question. i'm just trying to clarify and formalize the properties for $\widetilde X$ that i need, and your comments are certainly very helpful. so let the map $G\to\widetilde G$ be arbitrary homomorphism, not necessary an embedding